# Best way to Create Application Headers using ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I have seen this Extjs Kitchen Sink Example:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/extjs-build/examples/kitchensink/index.html

I think have create it using css .. is there any other recommended way to create something like tabbed headers ?

What if i want to add something like a "Whos logged in?" kind of feature?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a specific reason you use extjs 4.1 ? 4.2.2 is the current version.

Comment: I didn't really understand your question. What's the relation between tabs and who's logged in ?

Comment: Its like Facebook top Header .. which can show you features like "your Name" with a menu in it..

and below a navigation tabs to show different content
@LorenzMeyer

Comment: ExtJs has tabs. So you can use Ext.tab.Panel (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel)